# Why using PnPO365ManagementShell parameter with Connect-PnPOnline allows to be multitenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, tenant

I cannot find enough information googling about this issue and I would like to understand why connecting to a *SharePoint Online* tenant with this parameter, `PnPO365ManagementShell` allows me to work in a multitenant way. I would like to know what are the things I'm able to do differently from running the command with `SPOManagementShell` parameter.